# what is the effect of temperature on the resistance of a photoconductor?

Tags: experimental-physics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory

As we know, for a photo conductor resistance tends to decrease with increase in irradiance, but with greater irradiance comes greater temperature. Also we know, photo conductors are semiconductors,whose resistance decrease with increasing temperature. So, can we link these two effects (increasing irradiance and increasing temperature) and say that the amount of decrease in resistance observed is cumulative effect of both?
Any mathematical relation will also be helpful.
Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Good.  http://able2know.org/topic/320522-1

Comment: Do you know any formula for dependence of resistance on irradiance?

Comment: No. Conductivity seems to increase ALMOST linearly with increase in irradiance. If (cos a)^2 is taken as a relative measure of irradiance,(a being the angle between polariser and analyser) then resistance of a photo conductor decreases linearly with it.

Comment: What is the purpose of your question?  How does this relate to your experiment?  You have varied irradiance, but I doubt that you are  controlling or measuring temperature also.  Are you trying to find the connection between irradiance and conductance, or between temperature and conductance?  Or both?

Comment: No. I don't control the temperature and am barely correlating conductivity and irradiance. I am just curious whether in my result effect of temperature is also creeping in.